# is there a method to verify existence of column in another pandas df?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe like :

```
Name; address ; firstname ; lastname ; postal_city ; number
Martin Lustig; Paris France; Martin; Fabien ; Paris ; 0
Adrian Dubois; Lille France; Adrian; Dubois; Nantes ; 0
```

in this case i want to add a new column "number" initialized to 0:

- if firstname in Name ==> number+1
- if lastname in Name ==> number+1
- if postal_city in address ==> number+1

for example for my dataframe, i shoud have in output :

```
Name; address ; firstname ; lastname ; postal_city ; number
Martin Lustig; Paris France; Martin; Fabien ; Paris  ; 2
Adrian Dubois; Lille France; Adrian; Dubois; Lille ; 3
```

Comment: you need to loop to check if a string is a substring in another column

Comment: how can i do this with pandas , im begginer

Comment: have you already read the duplicate link? Try this first, make an attempt and update your question if needed

Comment: yes but if we want to do the verification at the same time , i .e for the 3 columns

Comment: how we can increment +1  ?  not put TRUE OR FALSE